# 2008 R2 Hyper-v guests are corrupting network traffic

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I've looked around quite extensively and can't seem to figure out why this might be happening.   On my 2008 R2 guest running the notepad++ installer gives me:

npp.5.8.5.Installer.exe - Entry Point Not Found

The procedure entry point pboard could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll

It's not just this software, cygwin's setup.exe just crashes on start with:

setup.exe has stopped working.

It's an APPCRASH with Exception code c0000005

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Tried with a Windows 7 x64 guest and had the same problems.

The strangest thing is that in both cases the OS seems to run fine.  Only things I try to install seem to be having problems.

Edit: Further Strangeness.  I just installed VS2010 off a mounted ISO without issue.  Is it possible that things are being corrupted by my network card at download time?

Edit: Trying to install google chrome seems to reinforce that packets are somehow getting munged in the virtual network adapter.

"- File, GoogleUpdateSetup.exem has a different computed hash than specified in manifest."

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening on all of your Windows guests, I'd assume that there is something fundamentally wrong with the Hyper-V host.

Have you had Hyper-V virtual machines running on that computer in the past, with no problems?

Have you got a processor that supports Intel-VT or AMD-V and have that enabled in the BIOS settings?

If you have, try saving the VMs, and if the VHDs are in the default location (why?), move them to another disk or partition and reinstall the Hyper-V host OS or Windows Server 2008 R2 (whichever you are using).

Comment: The host runs the very same software just fine.  I'll double check the bios settings and get back to you.

Comment: @Rick: What I meant was: Did you have Hyper-V (and VMs) running succesfully on the same machine in the past? ie. Is this a new problem that has occured?

Comment: Actually, the machine is a brand new HP DL580 G7 with 256GB of ram and 8 quad core Xeons.  It's out first server at a brand new company.

Comment: @Rick: I cannot think of anything further.  You could consider using VMware ESXi instead.  It's not much more difficult to use.  I have voted to migrate this to Server Fault.